# Why does OWSLib's getfeature(..., filter=...) not filter?

Tags: python, wfs, owslib

I am struggling to make a filter effective for a `GetFeature` request with [OWSLib](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/). Here's the code I wrote so far (I'm extracting data from Berlin's open geodata-server):

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


wfs = WebFeatureService("http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_vms_detailnetz_str", "1.1.0")
filter_ = PropertyIsLike(propertyname='BEZIRK', literal='Mitte', wildCard='*')
filterxml = ET.tostring(filter_.toXML()).decode("utf-8")
res = list(ET.fromstring(wfs.getfeature(typename="fis:re_vms_detailnetz_str", propertyname="BEZIRK", filter=filterxml, maxfeatures=10).read()))
```

This code is copied from the [OWSLib sample section on WFS](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wfs). However, this has not the intended effect, since I get:

```
print list(list(res[1])[0])[4].tag  # -> '{http://www.berlin.de/broker}BEZIRK'
print list(list(res[1])[0])[4].text # -> 'Spandau' != 'Mitte' -- Oops?
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the version 1.1.0 [GetCapabilities response](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_vms_detailnetz_str?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0&) for that service, it appears that `PropertyIsLike` is not a supported comparison operator.

```
<ogc:ComparisonOperators>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>LessThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>NullCheck</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThan</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>GreaterThanEqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>Like</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>EqualTo</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
    <ogc:ComparisonOperator>Between</ogc:ComparisonOperator>
</ogc:ComparisonOperators>
```

It is supported at [version 2.0.0](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_vms_detailnetz_str?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=2.0.0&)

```
<fes:ComparisonOperators>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLessThan"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsGreaterThan"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsEqualTo"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsNotEqualTo"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLike"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsBetween"/>
    <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsNull"/>
</fes:ComparisonOperators>
```

So you should change:

`wfs = WebFeatureService("http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_vms_detailnetz_str", "1.1.0")`

for

`wfs = WebFeatureService("http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_vms_detailnetz_str", "2.0.0")`